# A simple and common word probably with rare definition

Tags: single-word-requests

I am pretty sure I saw this rare definition in Wiktionary, which might not be 100% accurate with the wordings, but it goes like "put the male genital from one side to another in trousers". At the first glance, I thought it's so hilarious but the next day I totally forgot which word it was. All I can tell is that's a common and simple word we might use in daily life.

It's definitely a definition from wiktionary.

Answer (score 4):

Wiktionary definition: **dress** 'Of a man, to allow the genitals to fall to one side or other within the trousers' [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dress#Verb)

When you're fitted by a tailor, they'll ask if you **dress 'right' or 'left'**. They're asking you if your appendage naturally hangs to the left or right of your trousers' crotch. ... In a well-fitted pair of pants, no one should be able to see which side you 'hang'. The majority of men dress to the left.

For tailored pants, an allowance in cloth is made! Some say a man's choice of sides can dictate all manner of things: [desperateman](http://thedesperateman.blogspot.com/2012/07/dressing-left.html)

> George Bush, who is a right dresser once said – or maybe it was Will
>   Farrell, who dresses left, pretending to be George Bush who said it –
>   or wait, no, maybe it was Justice Antonin Scalia - but whoever said
>   it, it still holds true –

Comment: It might be useful to include the link back to the wiktionary definition 'Of a man, to allow the genitals to fall to one side or other within the trousers' https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dress#Verb

Comment: Well that's educational!